# The link between FWER and max/min statistic

Tags: multiple-comparisons, familywise-error

I am currently looking at lecture slides about fMRI data and I have the following:

Let $H_{0_i}$ be the hypothesis that there is no activation in voxel $i$ (a cube area in the brain, a 3d version of a pixel) where $i \in \{1,\ldots,m \}$ (i.e. there is $m$ voxels in total). Let $T_i$ be the value of the test statistic at voxel $i$. The family-wise null hypothesis, $H_0$, thates that there is no activation in any of the $m$ voxels $$H_0 = \bigcap\limits_{i \in V}H_{0_i}$$,

Using Bonferroni correction, the idea is we can choose a threshold FWER of $\alpha$ by choosing a threshold $u$ such that $\mathbb{P}(T_i \geq u | H_0) \leq \frac\alpha m$. Then: \begin{align}
FWER &= \mathbb{P}\left( \bigcup\limits_{i \in V} (T_i \geq u) | H_0 \right) \\ &\leq \sum\limits_{i \in V} \mathbb{P} (T_i \geq u | H_0) \\
&\leq \sum\limits_{i \in V} \frac\alpha m = \alpha
\end{align}

All good so far (I think). But then I come to a slide that says there is a link between FWER and the max statistic it says

\begin{align}
FWER &= \mathbb{P}(FWE) \\
&=\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcup\limits_{i \in V} (T_i \geq u) | H_0 \right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left( \max\limits_{i \in V} T_i \geq u | H_0 \right)
\end{align}

I feel like this is a typo and it should be min instead of max because, my intuition says $$\left( \bigcup\limits_{i \in V} (T_i \geq u) | H_0 \right)  \iff \left( \min\limits_{i \in V} T_i \geq u |H_0 \right) $$ But I wanted to check this because I couldn't find anything online (other than lecture slides which are near enough identical to my reference) and my intuition often gets me into trouble when I do statistics.

Comment: Hint: Say (out loud!) the associated probability statement using the word "or" to construct the union of the events. Simplify it to the case of two events if that helps. Then "generalize" back to the full case.

Comment: Of course, I was thinking that all $T_i$ had to be larger than $u$, but that would be intersection (AND) not union (OR)! If you put your comment into answer form, I'd be happy to accept it @cardinal :) Thanks

Comment: @cardinal I know this is an old question but if you would like to make your comment into an answer I'd be happy to accept